# Linux Scheduler FIFO don't work as expected

Tags: linux, pthreads, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want to use the scheduler in this way:

**Example**

- 3 pthreads with different priority ( 0 , 50 , 99 )

If the pthread with 99 is running, no other pthread is allowed to run.
The order of execution should be priority orientated

**My Implementation:**

every pthread is created with that sequence

```
struct sched_param schedparam;  // thread scheduler parameter

pthread_create(threadPtr,NULL,(void *)entryPt,NULL);

pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(attrPtr, SCHED_FIFO);

schedparam.__sched_priority=priority;

pthread_attr_setschedparam(attrPtr, &schedparam );

pthread_setschedparam(threadId,SCHED_FIFO,&schedparam );
```

But it doesn't work.

**Behavior:**

pthreads are executed in the same order as they are created.

Comment: Make the thread with priority 99 a busy-wait loop that does not perform any I/O; does your problem persist? Also verify your program runs with superuser privileges.

Answer (score 1):

'pthreads are executed in the same order as they are created': if you have three or more free cores, then that is the expected behaviour - all threads have different priorities, but there are enough resources to run them all, so they all run.

Even if you have only one core, many OS schedulers have anti-starvation algorithms that gradually raise the dynamic priority of low-priority threads so that they eventually get to run, (a bit). This scheme can help on an overloaded box if the low-priority thread has obtained a lock, is then preempted and then cannot proceed, causing problems elsewhere, (priority inversion).

If you want such 'strange' behaviour as you post, you will have to actually code it with suitable inter thread comms to prevent the other threads from ever running while the important thread is.

Edit:

'pthreads are executed in the same order as they are created' - how do you know this?  What do the threads do?  Do they run forever?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your threads do not get blocked on I/O or yield (please show code), this could be due to:

- Non-superuser threads not allowed to run above priority 19
- `sysctl` settings limiting amount of time available to each thread, for instance:

  - kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
  - kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000, allowing threads to only run 95% of each second.